Android SDK version found: "Version supported: .a.a"?
Unable to build my react-native app due to Android SDK not found even I have installed all the require SDKs and other build tools and also set environment variables.
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
 ✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: 29.0.2, 31.0.0, 34.0.0
   - Version supported: .a.a

